# Como fazer um sorteio de um elemento de um array dentro de um intervalo específico?

Tags: python, random

Eu tenho um código em Python, onde tenho um array (g) de 10000 elementos. Após realizo um sorteio utilizando random.choice(g) que sorteia qualquer um desses 10000 elementos. Entretanto, eu gostaria que o meu valor final ficasse entre um determinado intervalo, porque eventualmente o sorteio acaba pegando valores fora do intervalo.

Primeiramente coloquei codição de if e else, mas eventualmente acontece de sortear valores fora do intervalo, pois essas codições só impedem isso de acontecer na primeira vez. Pensei em colocar um loop while, mas não estou conseguindo implementar isso.
Abaixo está parte do código

Basicamente, é aqui que eu gero meu array com 10000 elementos

```
mu = 0.7416
sigma = 0.0876
g = np.random.normal (mu, sigma, 10000)
```

Aqui é somente o valor médio da distribuição gerada, nada que influencie na minha dúvida

```
def calculo_dist_internuclear():
    media = stats.gmean(g, axis=0)
    return media
print ('Distância internuclear mais provável:', calculo_dist_internuclear()
```

Aqui realizo o sorteio do array gerado

```
valor_escolhido = random.choice(g)
print ('O valor sorteado foi:', valor_escolhido)

if (0.5916 < valor_escolhido < 0.8916):
    valor_escolhido_FC1 = valor_escolhido
    print ("Sorteio de primeira:", valor_escolhido_FC1)

else:
    valor_escolhido_FC2 = random.choice(g)
    print ("Sorteio realizado novamente:", valor_escolhido_FC2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá viva para além do random existem mais opções....randrange e uniform para inteiros e para floats.

O teu exemplo com os dois, ajusta ao que precisas.

```
from random import randrange, uniform

# randrange returns one integral value
valor_escolhido = randrange(0, 10000)
print ('O valor sorteado foi:', valor_escolhido)

if (0.5916 < valor_escolhido < 0.8916):
    valor_escolhido_FC1 = valor_escolhido
    print ("Sorteio de primeira:", valor_escolhido_FC1)

else:
    # uniform returns floating-point value
    valor_escolhido_FC2 = uniform(0, 10000)
    print ("Sorteio realizado novamente:", valor_escolhido_FC2)
```